# Writing mocks using moq for a method

Tags: c#, mstest

I have the method below I will like to unit test. I am using mstest. Notice how CatService
is used to call 2 other methods

This line of code gets a service of Type T

```
    _provider.GetNecessaryService<IJohnsonProject>() gets a service of Type T
```

Here is the method

```
    public async Task<(bool, string)> AddDataAsync(DataDto firstSet)
    {
        try
        {
            var CatService = _provider.GetNecessaryService<IJohnsonProject>();

            var dto = _mapper.Map<MyDto>(firstSet);

            var reply = await CatService.AddInfoAsync(dto);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstSet.ImageMime) && firstSet.Image.Length > 0)
            {
                await CatService.AddPictureAsync(reply.Id, firstSet.Image, firstSet.ImageMime);
            }

            return (true, reply.Id);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return (false, ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I started thinking I have to write some Mocks. The first one I have below should return a service type of T

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task MyFirstTest(){
        
         var CatService = _mockprovider.Setup(x => x.GetNecessaryService<IJohnsonProject>());
    }
```

What is the best way to Mock these two lines ?

```
    var reply = await CatService.AddInfoAsync(dto);
    
    await CatService.AddPictureAsync(reply.Id, firstSet.Image, firstSet.ImageMime);
```

Answer (score -1):

`_provider` is a factory pattern, therefore you need to implement a mocked up version of the objects that it returns too:

```
var mockedJohnsonProject = new Mock<IJohnsonProject>();
mockedJohnsonProject.Setup(x=>x.AddInfoAsync(It.IsAny<MyDto>());

var CatService = _mockprovider.Setup(x => x.GetNecessaryService<IJohnsonProject>())
    .Returns(mockedJohnsonProject.Object);
```

Comment: How about this line    await CatService.AddPictureAsync(reply.Id, firstSet.Image, firstSet.ImageMime);  ?

Comment: How can I mock this line  _provider.GetNecessaryService<IJohnsonProject>()? This is constantly failing

Comment: How is it failing?